# std::vector::erase with equal arguments

Tags: c++, stl

Is it safe to call iterative methods such as STL container erase (the override taking 2 iterators), e.g. in my case `std::vector::erase()`, with both arguments being `vec.end()`? I made an experiment and it looks like the call just does nothing, but I want to be sure I can use it safely in the code, otherwise I have to test my iterators and avoid `erase()` if they're equal.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Is it standard? I mean, can I fully rely on that, compiler-independent? cplusplus.com and cppreference.com don't explain this special case...

Comment: Yes, it's safe everywhere. It's not a special case; `erase` removes all elements in the range `[a, b)`, and if `a == b`, it removes no elements.

Comment: @SethCarnegie general StackOverflow question, what do I do if I get the answer in comments? I can't mark the question as answered

Comment: @Seth Technically, you were first to answer this, so if you want to, you can answer this and I'll delete mine.

Comment: Just make sure you use real iterators! The phrase 'invalid arguments' could cover a multitude of sins, most of which are NOT OK.

Comment: @us2012 He wasn't the first to answer, he was the first to comment.

Comment: @fr33domlover if someone answers in the comments then just take the knowledge and mark some other answer as the answer. Perhaps if they give some indication that they're going to write a real answer, you might want to wait for them and accept their answer if you feel like it, but I'm not going to write one (I generally only answer yes/no questions in comments).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ Standard (n3337), 23.2.3, Sequence containers, Table 100 ('sequence container requirements) - row `a.erase(q1,q2)`:

> Effects: Erases the elements in the range `[q1,q2)`.

This means that `a.erase(q,q)` is safe because it does nothing.

Loki Astari's answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656) has a list of drafts of the C++ standard. The official copy is not freely available unfortunately, so I am using n3337, which seems to be the closest to C++11.

Comment: Can you add a link if possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is safe ; it is an effective no-op because end() -> end() is a range that is empty.